# Sorting in Ascending Order in Scheme Programming

Tags: racket

I would like to sort some data and I would like to use symbol

Answer (score 1):

I believe Racket's `sort` can do what you want, with the appropriate `less-than` and `#:key` parameter. For example:

```
>  (sort '((strawberry 5 zambia) (banana 2 sweden))
         symbol<?
         #:key first)
```

=>

```
'((banana 2 sweden) (strawberry 5 zambia))
```

See the [`sort` docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=sort#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In R6RS Scheme you have `list-sort` (in R6RS) and it takes a comparison procedure as first argument and the list of data as the second.

You don't show how your `fruit-list` looks like but if it's close to what you want as output you can do:

```scm
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs)
        (only (srfi :1) fold))

(define (make-cmp cmp accessor)
  (lambda (x y)
    (cmp (accessor x) (accessor y))))

(define (compose . lst)
  (define cmds (reverse lst))
  (lambda (x)
    (fold (lambda (proc arg) (proc arg))
          x
          cmds)))

(define (sorted-via obj what)  
  (define <fruitname? (make-cmp string<? (compose symbol->string car)))
  (define <location?  (make-cmp string<? (compose symbol->string caddr)))
  (define <number?    (make-cmp < cadr))

  (cons 'fruits
        (list-sort (case what
                     ((fruitname) <fruitname?)
                     ((location)  <location?)
                     ((number)    <number?)
                     (else (raise 'invalid-sort-field)))
                   (cdr obj))))
```

R7RS-small, like R5RS,  doesn't have a sort procedure so it's back to [SRFI-95 Sorting and merging](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-95/srfi-95.html) which looks similar to #!racket:

```scm
#!r7rs
(import (scheme)
        (only (srfi :1) fold)
        (srfi :95))

(define (sorted-via obj what)  
  (cons 'fruits
        (sort (cdr obj)
              (if (eq? what 'number) < string<?)
              (case what
                ((fruitname) (compose symbol->string car))
                ((location)  (compose symbol->string caddr))
                ((number)    cadr)
                (else (raise 'invalid-sort-field))))))
```

And if you want to use #!racket:

```scm
#!racket
(define (sorted-via obj what)  
  (cons 'fruits
        (sort (cdr obj)
              (if (eq? what 'number) < symbol<?)
              #:key (case what
                      ((fruitname) car)
                      ((location)  caddr)
                      ((number)    cadr)
                      (else (raise 'invalid-sort-field))))))
```