# Name for applying list of functions to a value?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Generally you think of applying one function to a list of values, thereby creating a new list (the associated Python function is `map`).  However, what if you apply a list of functions to one value, thereby creating a new value?  For example:

```
allCaps = lambda s: s.upper()
exclaim = lambda s: s + '!'
quote = lambda s: '"' + s + '"'

funcs = [allCaps, exclaim, quote]
value = 'hello'
for f in funcs:
    value = f(value)
print(value) # "HELLO!"
```

Is there a name for this sort of operation (similar to map, filter, reduce)?

Comment: `map` and `reduce` are the name for this sort of operation. That the list elements are used as functions doesn't change anything. I've used both `map` and `reduce`(`fold`) in this way a [couple of times in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23319217/1565698).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) for this, just pass 'hello' as the initial(`reduce(function, sequence[, initial])`) value.:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), funcs, 'hello')
'"HELLO!"'
```

Comment: I understand how to implement this (thanks though), but I was wondering if there's a name for this operation specifically - reduce is more generic than this.